# Can upload through FTP but not through WP uploader

Tags: uploads

Uploading through the WP uploader gives me a "failed to write to disk error". However, I can upload through FTP. Does that mean that the temporary directory is full and I have to contact my hosting provider to empty it?

Edit: My permissions are all set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. It might be only a problem with the file permissions. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions for more information.

Comment: It could also be the folder is "owned" by the wrong user. Usually your host can help whether it's permissions or ownership.